# Django FormWizard and view

Tags: django, formwizard

Basically, I just want to be able to get the parameter community_name, can this be done with

```
(r'^(?P<community_name>\w+)/matches/submit/$', MatchWizard([MatchStep1Form, MatchStep2Form, MatchStep3Form])),
```

or do I need a view?
If I have a view, I can have the URLConf like

```
(r'^(?P<community_name>\w+)/matches/submit/$', "matches.views.submit_form"),
```

and do the normal view procedure, `def submit_form(request, community_name):`

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting the solution I found out. After taking a look at the source code of `FormWizard`, I noticed the variable community_name is available at `kwargs` of `parse_params`

```
def parse_params(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    community = get_object_or_404(Community, slug=kwargs['community_name'])
    self.extra_context['community'] = community
```